# How to get Amazon SQS presigned url

Tags: amazon-sqs

I am very new to Amazon web services. I am able to generate presigned url for Amazon S3 but not for Amazon SQS.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SQS does not support the creation of a presigned URL. You can check out [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=116827) forum post for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have created a SQS Policy with sendMessage as action.Can I treat this queue url a kind of presigned url to send message.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate presigned urls for SQS using the REST api. Here's an example of a presigned url being creating for reading a message off a queue in Ruby using the aws sdk.

```
require "httparty"
require("aws-sdk")

message_body = { "hello": "world" }
msg_body_encoded = CGI.escape(message_body.to_json)

signer = Aws::Sigv4::Signer.new(
  service: "sqs",
  region: "us-east-1",
  access_key_id: "ACCESS KEY ID",
  secret_access_key: "SECRET ACCESS KEY"
)

presigned_url = signer.presign_url(
  http_method: "get",
  url: "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789/SomeQueueNmae.fifo/?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=#{msg_body_encoded}&MessageDeduplicationId=#{dedup_id}&MessageGroupId=Default",
  expires_in: 1000.day.to_i
)

response = HTTParty.get(presigned_url, headers: { "Accept": "application/json" })

puts presigned_url
puts response
# {"SendMessageResponse":{"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"12345678910-100c-510b-96af-12345678910"},"SendMessageResult":{"MD5OfMessageAttributes":null,"MD5OfMessageBody":"fbc24bcc7a1794758fc1327fcfebdaf6","MD5OfMessageSystemAttributes":null,"MessageId":"12345678910-db6c-4e17-b6ac-12345678910","SequenceNumber":"12345678910"}}}
```

[I've written an example for ReceiveMessage and SendMessage via Ruby in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/seveibar/2196c63fcb0b02fe5532d9d2d947cffe)